# How can i cache large image data using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser-cache

I am developing an ASP.NET WebAPI which is utilizing the features of HTML5. I need to cache image data for improving performance. The image data is returned in the JSON format from a web service which is hosted in IIS in separate machine. When I click on the thumbnail of an image in UI, it will call a webservice with a seriesID as input. Then the webservice will return imageID and pixel data stream. Then this pixel data stream is binding to a canvas. I need to cache the image which is shown in the canvas. The image is of around 70MB in size. So which feature of HTML5 can I use for caching this huge amount of image data?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the manifest a go: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Worked for me with smaller image sizes.